# How to use variables in vim command-like syntax?

Tags: vim

I want to write a function that can map a key to another function.

But I failed to insert the variables into `map` command:

`map a:key :! a:action` 
(in which `a:key` may be `<F9>`, `<C-F9>` and so on)

How to achieve this in vim command-like sentences?

Comment: Just for checking whether there is another way to go about this, what are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I want to write a function to map shortcut keys according to the file type. And I think it's better to make a function to avoid same code lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for `execute`.

```
:execute "map " . a:key . " :!" . a:action
```

See `:help :execute` for more information.